# How do i add a user name and a password to sqlmap?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection, sqlmap

I was running a SQLInjection with sqlmap. My page has an error of sql but the error shows up once you logged in your account(Example: page.com/login.php and when you log you go to page.com/index.php?id=1 and here the sql error is evident). When i run sqlmap on page.com/index.php?id=1 the page redirects the sqlmap to page.com/login.php.It's possible to provide sqlmap a user and a password to make sqlmap log in the account and then perform the SQLInjection?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 8):

You can use cookie parameter with sqlmap. First, log into your account and learn your cookie information then you can use `--cookie` parameter. For example when login my account, my cookie is `PHPSESSIONID=ajksdgadhakjsdhak`. After that, you could do just like command below in your terminal.

```
sqlmap.py --url http://page.com/index.php?id=1 --cookie='PHPSESSIONID=ajksdgadhakjsdhak' --dbs
```